# python len() throwing operator expected in django binding

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django, and have the following line of code in an html template:

```
{% if len(dato.titulo) > 35 %} {{dato.titulo[:35] + '...'}} {% else %} {{ dato.titulo }}{% endif %}
```

the `{% if len(dato.titulo) > 35 %}` bit throws the exception. I tried using a truncatechars filter but the django version installed is apparently old and doesn't have the filter. How could I make this work (truncate the string if it has more than 35 characters)?

Comment: Use `dato.titulo|length > 35`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In django template use [`|length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length) filter to get length of string, so update your line as

```
{% if dato.titulo|length > 35 %} {{dato.titulo[:35] + '...'}} {% else %} {{ dato.titulo }}{% endif %}
```

It seems you want to truncate the string, in that case you can use [`|truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filter. So no need to check length and manually truncate the string. Just do

```
{{ dato.titulo|truncatechars:35 }}
```

---

If no `truncatechars` available, use `|slice` as mentioned by *@Leonardo.Z*, it will truncate the string, but will not add `...` at the end.

```
{{ dato.titulo|slice:35 }}
```

---

Or write your own template filter to do this.

Comment: thanks! that fixed the error on my if, but now I get and error on `dato.titulo[:35]`, that says "}} expected"... Like I said in my question, I can't use truncatechars because my installed version of django doesn't support it and upgrading to the latest version isn't feasible right now. Any way to get around this?

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso change `dato.titulo[:35]` to `dato.titulo|slice:":35"`

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso Write a custom tag that does truncatechars functionality.

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso If you can not upgrade django. Please consider writing a templatetag. slicing does work on unicode.